# Se immune e immunitario sono entrambi aggettivi, come si distinguono dal punto di vista grammaticale?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, suffix

[**Immune** 1. Che non è soggetto a […]](https://treccani.it/vocabolario/immune)

[**Immunitario** 1. Relativo a[…]](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/immunitario/)

Mi viene naturale notare che se il primo aggettivo è X, il secondo è (circa) X-tario.

Credo che ci siano tante altre coppie di aggettivi come i due sopra citati, e immagino che tra i due rappresentanti di ogni coppia intercorra la stessa relazione grammaticale che tra i due sopra citati. (Salvo qualche eccezione?)

Hanno un nome queste due "categorie" di aggettivi? O sono solo due gruppi di aggettivi che io immagino

Al di là del ruolo che i due aggettivi hanno nella frase, noto che il primo è formato da *immun-* con suffisso *-e* che gli attribuisce il numero, mentre il secondo è formato sulla base del primo con un il suffisso (o infisso, o "pezzo nel mezzo") *-tari-* seguito dal suffisso *-o*.

Non ho studiato linguistica, ma credo che tutti i suffissi che connotano genere e numero di una parola appartengano ad una stessa categoria, mentre quelli che ne fanno un avverbio, come *-mente*, rientrino in un'altra.

Quel suffisso (o qualunque cosa sia) *-tari-* ha un nome?

Comment: Dubito che ci sia una regola generale. *Immune* e *immunitario* significano cose diverse (ancorché collegate). *Immunitario* è derivato di *immunità*, a sua volta derivata da *immune*. Queste catene più o meno casuali di derivazioni sono abbastanza comuni nelle lingue.

Comment: Come osserva Denis, il suffisso “-tari-” non ha un nome perché non è un vero suffisso di per sé. “Immunitario” è l'aggettivo derivante da “immunità”, e la derivazione “immunità” > “immunitario” è analoga a quella che porta ad abitudinario, agrario, annonario, anticipatario e innumerevoli altri aggettivi in -ario.

Comment: Vedo che questo non-suffisso ha in _agrario_ effetto simile a quello che ha in _immunitario_, cioè esprime che l'elemento a cui l'aggettivo si riferisce *riguarda* una certa materia. Ed è così anche per _annonario_, a quanto leggo su Treccani. In parte lo è anche per abitudinario (_comportamento abitudinario_), ma in parte no (_persona abitudinaria_).

Comment: @Enlico, quelli sono solo i primi esempi in ordine alfabetico fra centinaia di aggettivi in “-ario” (“-ario” _è_ un suffisso; è “-tari-” che non lo è). Comunque hai ragione, sarebbe interessante studiare i vari diversi usi di “-ario”: qualcosa [c'è qui](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ario/), ma parla soprattutto delle versioni sostantivate degli aggettivi.

Comment: Sembra che la domanda nel titolo e quelle nel testo siano abbastanza diverse. Potresti chiarire cosa stai chiedendo?

Comment: Dal titolo dovrebbe essere chiaro che sto 1. considerando la categoria/l'insieme di tuti gli aggettivi, 2. facendo l'ipotesi che esistano (almeno) due sotto-categorie, 3. facendo l'ipotesi che i due aggettivi appartengano l'uno ad una categoria e l'altro all'altra. Nel test sto chiedendo se tali categorie hanno un nome. Infine, con l'ultima domanda, sto associando _-tari-_ a una delle due categorie. Il tutto è ovviamente un tentativo di capire se queste categorie esistono o meno. @FedericoPoloni, ho chiarito abbastanza?

Comment: Come ti è stato detto nei commenti, non esistono 'aggettivi in *-tari-*". Esistono aggettivo costruiti col suffisso "-ario", ma è una cosa ben diversa

Comment: @DenisNardin, certo, questo l'ho capito. È necessario che io cambi la domanda? Non è più giusto che le correzioni ai miei errori siano inclusi in una eventuale risposta?

Comment: E chi dice che esista una distinzione, dal punto di vista _grammaticale_? La distinzione (così come la loro relazione) è certamente semantica ma, dal punto di vista grammaticale, sono entrambi aggettivi qualificativi, no?

Comment: Non sono Denis, ma per rispondere alle tue domande (dell'ultimo commento): così com'è  la domanda, non è possibile darle una risposta. Dai per scontate delle cose che non corrispondono alla realtà della lingua italiana, e poi poni delle domande sulle cose che hai detto tu. È un po' come chiedere perché le zebre hanno le corna... :)

Comment: @DaG, non direi. Se è come dici, allora la risposta a _Hanno un nome queste due "categorie" di aggettivi?_ è _no, non ce l'hanno perché non sono riconosciute dalla lingua italiana_; a _Quel suffisso -tari- ha un nome?_ la risposta è _no, non ce l'ha_, e così via. Non ho chiesto perché le zembre hanno le corna, ma _se_ le zembre hanno le corna e, in caso affermativo, se le rigature gialle e blu sulle corna hanno un nome.

Comment: @Enlico: Diciamo che hai chiesto se le corna delle zebre hanno un nome. Cito: «Hanno un nome queste due "categorie" di aggettivi?», e idem per il presunto suffisso. Comunque mi scuso se il mio precedente commento è suonato più antipatico di quanto fosse mia intenzione.

Comment: @DaG, mi trovo ancora in disaccordo. È forse mal posta, ad esempio, la domanda "ha un nome la categoria di aggettivi qualificativi applicabili al sostantivo pentola, come _ampia_, _metallica_, _fredda_, e _incandescente_?" A me sembra ben posta, tanto quanto mi aspetto che la risposta sia "no, non ha un nome perché non servirebbe a nulla formalizzarla". O forse sto utilizzando male il termine "categoria"? Se sì, illuminami sulla definizione assiomatica del termine.

Comment: Non so illuminarti, @Enlico, visto che non capisco cosa intendi. Sarà un limite mio. Non ti faccio perdere ulteriore tempo.

Comment: @DaG, ho solo chiesto se è lecito utilizzare il termine "categoria" per indicare una qualsiasi accozzaglia di parole che abbiano qualcosa in comune. Gli aggettivi _agrario_, _anticipatario_, _immunitario_ hanno qualcosa (proprietà, caratteristica, ...) che manca agli aggettivi _agreste_, _anticipato_, _immune_? A me sembra di sì, se non altro perché i primi terminano tutti allo stesso modo. Possiamo mettere gli uni e gli altri in due cateorie, insiemi, zainetti, o contenitori diversi? E io sto chidendo se nella lingua italiana questi "contenitori" sono stati battezzati in qualche modo.