# Gli aggettivi esprimenti l'idea che il sostantivo a cui si riferiscono sia "relativo a qualcosa" sono annoverati in un comune insieme di aggettivi?

Tags: adjectives

[A seguito del fallimento nel porre una domanda che mi sembrava scontato ammettesse come risposte unicamente *sì* e *no*](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/13574/se-immune-e-immunitario-sono-entrambi-aggettivi-come-si-distinguono-dal-punto-d), proverò a formularne una simile, con la finalità di soddisfare la stessa curiosità, in fondo.

La domanda è quella nel titolo:

**Gli aggettivi esprimenti l'idea che il sostantivo a cui si riferiscono sia "relativo a qualcosa" sono annoverati in un comune insieme di aggettivi?**

Esempi di aggettivi che esprimono la suddetta idea:

- [Immunitario - *Relativo a* ...](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/immunitario/)
- [Agrario - *Che riguarda* ...](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/agrario)

Esempi di aggettivi che non esprimono la suddetta idea:

- Bello
- Scontato
- Inutile

Sono interessato ad una risposta che sia *sì* o *no*, accompagnata da una fonte a supporto, in quanto non sono stato in grado di trovare alcunché a riguardo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mi risulta che gli aggettivi si distinguano in *qualificativi* (che danno informazioni su caratteristiche intrinseche di ciò a cui si riferiscono - es. "blu", "grande", "buono", etc.) e *determinativi* (che danno informazioni sul rapporto esistente fra ciò a cui si riferiscono ed altro - es. "primo", "mio", "questo", etc.).

Gli aggettivi qualificativi si suddividono in *primitivi* (es. "dolce"), *derivati* (es. "musicale" da musica), *alterati* (es. "dolciastro") e *composti* (es. "agrodolce").

Gli aggettivi a cui fai riferimento sono quindi aggettivi *qualificativi derivati*.

Il [sito della Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/aggettivi-qualificativi_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) usa l'espressione aggettivi qualificativi *di relazione* per fare riferimento agli aggettivi che esprimono l'idea di "che riguarda...", "relativo a..." ma fra questi non rientrano solo gli aggettivi con suffisso in *-ario* (che sembrava essere il fulcro della tua domanda precedente), come risulta evidente dagli esempi riportati sul sito.

Inoltre, a mio avviso, la classificazione di un aggettivo come "di relazione" sembra legata più al contesto in cui è usato che ad una rigida regola grammaticale. Ad esempio:

- Un suono molto musicale (in cui "musicale" indica una qualità del suono)
- L'industria musicale (in cui "musicale" indica una relazione)

In sintesi, quindi, la risposta alla tua domanda è "no" ma difficilmente troverai una fonte che lo dica esplicitamente, per lo stesso motivo per cui non troverai fonti che dicano esplicitamente che non esiste una legge che ti vieta di respirare: normalmente la gente si prende la briga di dimostrare ciò che è, non tutto ciò che non è. ;)